# Visual studio Online build services, git tag

Tags: msbuild, azure-devops, git-tag

I'm trying to get VSO build services to tag the build number into git upon a successful build.

Any ideas on how I'd achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is now possible as part of the build process if git is hosted on vsts.

Answer (score 1):

Create a post or pre build script that does the tag.

You should be using the *template.12.xaml that includes pre setup places to run batch or PowerShell scripts.

You can run scripts pre and post build ad well as pre and post test.

If you only want to tag on a successful build you can use post-test as the best place.